# Is there a way to filter out rows if the first value in the rows meets a certain criteria. R

Tags: r, indexing, filter

Is it possible to filter rows based on 1 value in that row? I am doing some sport stats analysis and I have a column that contains the final outcome and score like so: W 112-101. PS I know the `PlusMinus` doesn't make sense I am just trying to show the format of my code.

I would like to just pull all of the wins out of the data set. I have tried to use indexing but I am having a hard time. Thanks!

```
            Date                Home                 Away              PlusMinus         Final
1   Mon, Oct 29, 2018   Golden State Warriors   Chicago Bulls             36           W 149-124
2   Wed, Feb 6, 2019    Milwaukee Bucks         Washington Wizards        13           W 148-129
3   Fri, Jan 4, 2019    Milwaukee Bucks         Atlanta Hawks             39           L 112-144
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output.  Perhaps `subset(df1, grepl('^W', Final))`

Comment: @akrun it would just be a new dataset only containing the rows in ```Final``` that are a win, or in this case, "W"

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are a lot of SO posts already on filtering data, and it might help to see your approach, even if that's just for folks to help point you to preexisting posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a substring pattern match with `grepl` to return a logical vector for `subset`ing the rows

```
df2 <- subset(df1, grepl('^W', Final))
```

---

Or using `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df2 <- df1 %>%
           filter(str_detect(Final, '^W'))
```